# Is there a way to check for an exception without using try/catch in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am fairly new to Java, I have some code that will act on an array in a loop, and the array changes every loop. Sometimes the code will throw a IndexOutOfBoundsException, when the array is too short. Is there a way for me to only execute code if there is no exception thrown? I know in Javascript I could do something like

```
var a = arr[index];
if (!a === null) { //do something }
```

How would I achieve the same effect in Java?

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` has nothing to do with `null`. You can check the index before accessing the element.

Comment: Java doesn't have a `===` operator.

Answer (score 7):

You can check before accessing the array item at a certain index

```
if (arr != null && index >= 0 && index < arr.length) {
  // arr[i] exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only execute code if an exception is not thrown:

```
try {
  // Code that may throw an exception...

  // Only execute this if exception isn't thrown.
} catch (SomeException e) {
  // Handle exception.
}
```

But a better strategy is not to cause the exception in the first place. Aside from the ugly syntax above, exceptions are really slow, because they require a full stack trace to be built. By which I mean: they are probably fast enough for many applications, but building that stack trace that you're going to throw away immediately is just wasteful, and faster not to do.

The sort of exception you are talking about here is a *runtime exception*, which is a type of unchecked exception. Runtime exceptions are supposed to be thrown to indicate a programming error - in this case, that you've not checked if the array index is in bounds.

You can either check this with separate conditions:

```
if (i >= 0) {
  if (i < arr.length) {
    // Only execute this if index in bounds
  }
}
```

Or, use `&&`, which stops evaluating once an operand is false:

```
if (i >= 0 && i < arr.length) {
  // ...
}
```